# BIRT Report Error "Failed to prepare the query execution for the data set"

Tags: birt

Hi I am getting the below exception

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Query command is not valid.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.populateDimension(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:1358)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.populateDimensions(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:1204)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.createCube(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.materializeCube(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:739)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: Failed to prepare the query execution for the data set
```

I am new to BIRT Report, not sure why this error is getting generated.

Comment: can you clarify at what point you are getting the error & what versions of BIRT you are using?

Comment: I am using version 2.6.2. When i am trying to read from a csv file and insert the data in the report, i am getting this exception in the log and a blank report is getting generated

Comment: This error is generated when there is a problem with the query used to get the data for the report.  It's most often due to a syntax error in the SQL.  Use an external query editor to make sure your query is properly formed and retrieves the data you want.  Also, use the "Preview" selection at the bottom left of the data set editor to make sure your query works in BIRT before trying to generate the report.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the query as sometimes the same query generates the report. Checked with the preview tab also and the query is working fine